# How can I create an additional lo interface?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, networking, network-interface

I'm trying to listen to two different interfaces that are loopbacks on a single Linux machine using wireshark.  Since I'll need to listen to the new interface, I'll need to be able to send data to the interface.  Meaning it will require an ip address that I can send data to via netcat.

I've seen a method to add different loopback interfaces [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444124/how-to-add-a-loopback-interface), but that doesn't actually add an interface option, just seems to assign a separate ip address to the single lo interface.

I also tried adding the lo2 loopback interface to `/etc/network/interfaces` file, and after reboot, it didn't appear to do anything.  Also, `sudo ifup lo2` didn't work either.

This is Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, and I need to keep it to a desktop version of a Debian based distro.

Is there a way to add an additional loopback with a separate interface name?

Comment: From [`.../drivers/net/loopback.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/loopback.c) :  /* The loopback device is special. There is only one instance per network namespace. */

Comment: It says, "There is only one instance", not, "There can only be one" (HighLOnder), which would mean there's still a possibility.  I have faith!

Comment: To be honest, I thought I'd get several hundred upvotes for the HighLOnder line.

Answer (score 1):

Install the `uml-utilities` package:

```
sudo apt install uml-utilities
```

Create a loopback interface :

```
sudo tunctl
```

Sample output:

```
Set 'tap0' persistent and owned by uid 0
```

Bring up the `tap0` interface:

```
sudo ifconfig tap0 up
```

To remove the `tap0` run : `tunctl -d tap0`

To assign an Ip address :

```
 sudo ifconfig tap0 192.168.0.254 up
```

Sample output:

```
tap0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.254  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether ce:bd:dd:0f:08:c8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

e,g 2:

```
$ sudo ifconfig tap0 127.0.0.1 up
tap0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0  broadcast 127.255.255.255
```

[Tap interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP)

[`man tunctl`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tunctl)

Comment: Thanks, while that does add an additional loopback interface, it doesn't assign it an ip address (similar to 127.0.0.x, or anything else).  Is there a way so that this interface is reachable via something I can see on wireshark?

Comment: I did try ```ifconfig tap0 127.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up```, but everything seems to still go through the 127.0.0.1 (lo) interface.  Nothing is seen on wireshark actually going to the tap0 interface.

Comment: @trueCamelType, the `tap` interface will not have the `IFF_LOOPBACK` flag set, so won't be a true loopback interface, even if you assign it an IP address in `127/8`.